# Starting service from intent in another service gets a run time error

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an error when trying to start a service with an intent from another service in an Android 2.3.3 project. The error is: Unable to start service with Intent{ act=(class name) cmp=(class name)/.(android name) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:provider==null

Method Call:

```
private void startLocationService(){
    intent = new Intent("com.example.Android.LocationService");
    intent.setClass(MainService.this.getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".LocationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.Android.LocationService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem a provider in LocationService.class ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually did forget the permissions which caused my provider in my LocationService to be null.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint in your `LocationService.onCreate()` for debug to see if it can goes there. Maybe the problem is not what you give here.

ps.

If you just need to use an explicit Intent (application-internal use), the `action` parts of both Java code and Manifest is redundant.